# How to compose Closeable objects in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a Java class which manages multiple `Closeable` resources. The C++ solution would be straightforward and easily scalable with a larger number of resources:

```
class composed_resource
{
    resource_a a;
    resource_b b;
    resource_c c;

    composed_resource(int x)
        : a(x), b(x), c(x)
    { }

    ~composed_resource()
    { }
};
```

My naive Java solution:

```
public class ComposedResource implements Closeable
{
    private final ResourceA a;
    private final ResourceB b;
    private final ResourceC c;

    public ComposedResource(int x) /* throws ... */ {
        a = new ResourceA(x);
        try {
            b = new ResourceB(x);
            try {
                c = new ResourceC(x);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                b.close();
                throw t;
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            a.close();
            throw t;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            a.close();
        } finally {
            try {
                b.close();
            } finally {
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A slightly improved version:

```
public class ComposedResource2 implements Closeable
{
    private final ResourceA a;
    private final ResourceB b;
    private final ResourceC c;

    public ComposedResource2(int x) /* throws ... */ {
        try {
            a = new ResourceA(x);
            b = new ResourceB(x);
            c = new ResourceC(x);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            close();
            throw t;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        try {
            if (a != null) a.close();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (b != null) b.close();
            } finally {
                if (c != null) c.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant solution which avoids nested try-catch-blocks while still maintaining exception safety? It is manageable with three resources, but anything more is getting unwieldy. (If it was a local scope, I could just use a "try-with-resources" statement, but that's not applicable here.)

---

I thought about this while working with `java.rmi`. In the constructor I'm creating/looking up the registry, looking up objects and exporting objects. The close() needs to unregister and unexport objects. I thought about creating wrapper objects to handle the export/unexport (like I'd do in C++ to take advantage of RAII), but then I noticed that won't help me much (I'm not that much of a Java expert, but I have to use it for university).

At the moment I'm using something like `ComposedResource2` above, and it works fine. But now I'm interested to know if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you present a use case? Maybe working with a concrete example will produce a better answer than an abstract problem...

Comment: Why isn't a try-with-resource not applicable?

Comment: 1) Avoid creating resources in constructors -- they, ideally, should just assign parameters to fields, and I think RAII is not applicable here. 2) Use try-with-resources if possible (maybe it will be more possible for you when your constructor will work in "assignment mode" only). 3) You could write your `Closeable` decorator that would join multiple `Closeable` instances into a single instance. 4) Or you could use Guava `com.google.common.io.Closer`.

Comment: @AdamMichalik: I've added some details, but if possible I'd like to discuss it abstractly. In my opinion it doesn't matter much if these are files, sockets, or something else – if it can be created and has to be closed, you'd have to handle in some way like this to avoid leaking resources (whether that's file handles, or open server sockets, etc.)

Comment: you can store them in a list and close one by one

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv: Hmm, maybe I'm approaching this with the wrong (C++) mindset… maybe I can find a better design. Thanks for mentioning `com.google.common.io.Closer`. I won't be able to use it in my current project, but it's something to keep in mind for the future.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Well, I'd like the resource instances to live as long as the `ComposedResource` instance. The code which creates the `ComposedResource` can use a try-with-resources to manage it, if it wants to do that.

Comment: Also, if you're fine with static methods and a you think a decorator is an overkill (I personally think it is for a few reasons despite I suggested it above): https://gist.github.com/lyubomyr-shaydariv/e6a76630ff6284171aa5

Comment: Why `ResourceA|B|C` constructor throws an `Exception` ? Does `ResourceA|B|C` implements `Closeable` ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use try-with-resouces like this.

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
    try (Closeable cc = c;
         Closeable bb = b;
         Closeable aa = a;) {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: what if resource is null due to initialization errors?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker If b was null, a and c will be closed.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker `try-with-resources` is null-safe in Java: even if all `cc`, `bb`, and `aa` are null -- nothing fails. Also, uninitialized or poorly initialized objects must not be used and throw an initialization exception. The best case is always-well-initialized objects.

Comment: +1. But note that a constructor shouldn't call an overrideable method, so some sort of minor adjustment is needed. (One option: this logic can be moved to a private method that the constructor and `close()` both delegate to.)

Comment: Ah, that's very nice. @ruakh: Thanks for this tip, but why would that be a problem?

Comment: If somebody creates a class inherits ComposedResource2 and overwrites ```close()``` and it does not call ```super.close()``` then the constructor of ComposedResource2 calls the overwritten ```close()```. It raises resource leak.

Comment: @AngraMainyu: Parent-class constructors are called before any initializers in a child class. So suppose your child class has a field declared-and-initialized as `private Foo foo = new Foo();` . . . suddenly, if it overrides a method that can be called from a parent-class constructor, it has to support the possibility that `foo` is still null! It's just too messy and counterintuitive, too hard for the child-class owner to remember and keep track of.

Comment: @saka1029: That's true, but usually it's just handled with documentation (à la "if overriding this method, you must call the superclass implementation"), and isn't considered a huge deal. (Subclass owners understand that they don't always have 100% freedom when overriding methods. Having to call the superclass implementation is not an onerous requirement.)

Answer (score 1):

What about changing the close() on this way?

```
@Override
public void close() {
   close(a);
   close(b);
   close(c);
}

public void close(Closeable closeable) throws IOException{
       if (closeable != null){
            closeable.close();
       }
}
```

I think that its more clean...

Also you can manage the 3 resources as 'Closeables' and put them in an array so the ComposedResource will have as many resources as you want. Doing something like this:

```
public class ComposedResource{
    List<Closeable> resources = new ArrayList<Closeable>();

    public void add(Closeable c){
        resources.add(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void close(){
        for (Closeable r : resources){
          close(r);
        }
    }

    public void close(Closeable c){
        try{
           c.close();
        catch (IOException e){
           log(e);
        }
    }
}
```

So you will add the resources:

```
ComposedResource c = new ComposedResource();
c.add(new Resource1());
c.add(new Resource2());
c.add(new Resource3());
...
// do nice thinks
// and, to close;
c.close();
```

Edit:

@Mohit Kanwar suggests to throw the exception, that way:

```
@Override
public void close() throws IOException {
     for (Closeable r : resources){
         r.close(r);
     }
 }
```

And edited my code, @Lii says that doing this one exception will prevent closing all resources and I'm agree with Lii so I rejected Mohit's edit...

Comment: Shouldn't we throw the exception e after logging, if a resource is not being closed?

Comment: In your  solution, if the first resource throws when closed then the subsequent resources will not get closed. That's not how it should work!

Comment: @inigoD I understand it now. I am sorry for the wrong edit. I have raised a flag for the same since it costed you a downvote. sorry again :(

Comment: It might be a good idea to save all exceptions that have been thrown and throw them afterwards, when all resources have been closed. Otherwise errors might be hidden. This is what the [`Throwable#addSuppressed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#addSuppressed) method is for. I believe that is how the try-with-resource-statement works.

Comment: @indigoD somehow one edit that I made, is still in your answer (the first code component) please re-edit that too.

Comment: This code looks indeed cleaner. However in the first example, if e.g. `close(a)` throws an exception, `b` and `c` will not be closed.